# ckeditor view source after image inserted

Tags: jquery, image, ckeditor, wysiwyg

After switching to CKEditor from TinyMCE we have noticed there appears to be no way of configuring/overriding the way the source button works when an image is inserted into the content of the wysiwyg with the file manager.

Has anyone found a workaround for this?  I know it may be unsafe but I am trying to avoid having to rewrite the image plug in for this to work.

Here is the current setup we are using.

```
    //setup ckeditor basics
    var config = {
        skin:'kama',
        width:'725px',
        height: '400px',
        uiColor: '#F3F3F3'
    };
    //spellchecking
    config.extraPlugins = 'atd-ckeditor';
    config.atd_rpc = '/includes/javascript/plugins/ckeditor/plugins/atd-ckeditor/proxy.cfm?url='; 
  config.atd_api_key = '<cfoutput>#AtdApikey#</cfoutput>';
  config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/includes/javascript/plugins/filemanager/index.cfm?cktype=events';
    config.toolbar_Full =[
        { name: 'document', items : [ 
                'Maximize','Source','-',
                'Preview','Print','-',
                'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-',
                'Undo','Redo','Find','Replace','-',
                'SelectAll','-',
                'atd-ckeditor'] 
        },  
        '/',
        { name: 'editing', items : [ 
                'NumberedList','BulletedList','-',
                'Outdent','Indent','-',
                'Blockquote','-',
                'JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-'
                ,'BidiLtr','BidiRtl','-',
                'Link','Unlink','Anchor','Image','Table','HorizontalRule','SpecialChar' ] 
        },  
        '/',
        { name: 'styles', items : [
                'Format','FontSize','Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-',
                'TextColor','BGColor','-',
                'RemoveFormat' ]
        },
    ];
    //set drop downs
    config.format_tags = 'h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6'
    config.fontSize_sizes = '10/10px;12/12px;14/14px;16/16px;18/18px;20/20px;24/24px';
    config.disableNativeSpellChecker = true;
    config.browserContextMenuOnCtrl = false;
    config.toolbarCanCollapse = false;
    config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
    config.pasteFromWordPromptCleanup = true;
    config.pasteFromWordNumberedHeadingToList = true;
    config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';
    $("#Detail").ckeditor(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like I had a bad file cached in memory, after clearing my cache it worked